# Deploy Laravel project to hosting

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, composer-php

I downloaded the repo and I am trying to deploy it on the host. I moved files on server. Root looks like this:

```
ROOT-
   --lsapp
        ---app
        ---bootstrap
        ---config
        ---database
        ---resources
        ---routes
        ---storage
          ...
   --public_html
        ---css
        ---fonts
        ---js
        ---vendor
        ---index.php
         ...
```

In my public_html/index.php I have:

```
require __DIR__.'/../lsapp/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../lsapp/bootstrap/app.php';
```

But I have an error:

```
Warning: require(/home/platne/serwer22093/lsapp/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/platne/serwer22093/lsapp/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17



Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/platne/serwer22093/lsapp/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56-fpm/lib/php') in /home/platne/serwer22093/lsapp/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

I don't know how to fix it.
Maybe I should use `composer update --no-scripts` in cmd, but I have an error: `'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.
When I type `composer install` I have `Could not open input file: composer`

Could anyone help me deploy this project?

Comment: For some reason you've put `vendor` in `public_html` instead of `lsapp`. As for the second bit, have you installed composer on the server?

Comment: is it necessery to install composer on the server ?

Comment: If you want to use the composer command then yes, if you don't need to run it on the server, then no.

Comment: to deploy project i have to use command composer update --no-scripts. I cant install composer

Comment: Then you can always upload it with your project, it's only the one file and run that from your project dir or something. The main problem is your `vendor` folder's location though.

Comment: how you up you project for git??

Answer (score 1):

First you need to ssh into your hosting server and [install composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/), once completed you will be able to run **composer** commands.

If still can't find composer when trying to run it you may need to add it the PATH variable, also check that your PHP version(**php -v**) is compatible with your Laravel [version server requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation).